# Is it possible to make an android app that contains more than 500 activities ??

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-application, android-applicationinfo

I'm planning to make an android application which contains more than **500 activities**. what will happen? Is my application will crash or not? What problems can happen?

Comment: Why would you need 500 activities?

Comment: Quite a senseless question, in my opinion. It's like asking "Can I go 20 days without food?" Yes, you **probably** can, but why would you?

Answer (score 0):

The apk size will be probably larger than any other applications i know.
But if you just open activity that you need and finish another, it's OK. The APK won't crash.

Do you need 500 differents activities? or just different data?